# Cant transform in the right format date & hour from fullcalendar event object

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar
http://fullcalendar.io/.
Everytime a user is selecting a timeslot in my calendar, I want to get all events that are in the calendar and transfer them in a hidden field in my view :

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

});
```

I have a select callback :

```
select: function(start, end, id, allDay) {
var eventData = {
        start: start,
        end: end,
        unique_id: guid(),
        block:  true,
        editable: true,
        backgroundColor: "#469278"
      };
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true


       var all_events = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
       $.each(all_events, function(index, value) {
        console.log(value.start["_d"]);
        console.log(index);
           var day         = value.start["_d"].format("dddd");
           var start_time  = value.start["_d"].format("HH:mm");
           var end_time    = value.end["_d"].format("HH:mm");
           var id          = value.unique_id["_i"];
           var slot        = {
              day: day,
              start_time: start_time,
              end_time: end_time,
              id: id
            };
          array_all_events.push(slot);
          $("#dispo_array").val(JSON.stringify(array_all_events));
      });
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
    },
```

Here I am saying that everytime a user does a select action, I should get all events object :

```
var all_events = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
```

I then iterate on each one of them, transform them into the right format and send them into my hidden field.
I don't understand why I get an error on this line :

```
var day         = value.start["_d"].format("dddd");
```

Uncaught TypeError: value.start._d.format is not a function

Comment: when you console the value.start["_d"] it generated some output or not??

Comment: yes ! I get ```Tue Oct 06 2015 10:30:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)```for ex

Comment: The date format is generated is UTC format change it to desire format (hour: min: sec) after that you append it

Comment: @GuruprasadRao thanks it was that !

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.format` method is dependent on **moment library** and hence you should use it as below:

```
var day = moment(value.start["_d"]).format('dddd')
```

Same goes with other variables.